# Append a zero to value if necessary in SQL statement DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a complex SQL statement that I need to match up two table based on a join.  The the intial part of the complex query has a location number that is stored in a table as a Smallint and the second table has the Store number stored as a CHAR(4).  I have been able to cast the smallint to a char(4) like this:

```
CAST(STR_NBR AS CHAR(4)) AND LOCN_NBR
```

The issue is that because the Smallint suppresses the leading '0' the join returns null values from the right hand side of the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Example

```
Table set A(Smallint)             Table Set B (Char(4))
|   96     |                      |  096     |
|   97     |                      |  097     |
|   99     |                      |  099     |
|  100     |  <- These return  -> |  100     |
|  101     |  <- These return  -> |  101     |
|  102     |  <- These return  -> |  102     |
```

I need to add make it so that they all return, but since it is in a join statement how do you append a zero to the beginning and in certain conditions and not in others?

Comment: Why don't you cast the `char(4)` column as `smallint` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully match it out to obtain a 3 digit location number at all times by doing the following:

STR_NBR was originally defined as a SmallINT(2)
LOCN_NO was originally defined as a Char(4)

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE_A AS A
JOIN TABLE_B AS B
  ON CAST(SUBSTR(DIGITS(A.STR_NBR),3,3)AS CHAR(4)) = B.LOCN_NO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try LPAD function:

```
 LPAD(col,3,'0' )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000' || STR_NBR, 4)
FROM TABLE_A
```

Casting Table B's `CHAR` to tinyint would work as well:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B
  ON A.num = CAST(B.txt AS TINYINT)
```